# Powershell compare two folders and display files not in both showing files found in both?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a power shell script to compare two folders (including sub-folders) but only for .ini or .properties files

My script currently is this

```
$items1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\XYZ\new\"  -Include "*.properties", "*.ini" -recurse 
$items2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\XYZ\old\" -Include "*.properties", "*.ini" -recurse 

$diffent = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $items1 -DifferenceObject $items2
if ($diffent.count -eq 0) {
echo "No new files found"
}
else {
echo "The Following files are not in both directories"
foreach($item in $diffent){
    $path = $item.InputObject.FullName
    echo "$path"
    } }
```

It seems the includes are the problem but i dont understand why?

If i run the same script without the include it works as it should (apart from reporting files i dont care about because they are not .ini or .properties

I am very inexperienced with powershell so hopefully its something simple ive missed while researching this.

Comment: the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters of `G-CI` are wildly unreliable. [*sigh ...*] i recommend you do your filtering after your `G-CI` call. plus, it is worth remembering that only the `-Filter` parameter is handled by the filesystem. so your include/exclude stuff is run after the `G-CI` call returns what the filesystem sends.

Comment: I thought i read that you cant filter by more than one value?

Comment: correct ... but you can pipe the `G-CI` output to `Where-Object` and filter there. [*grin*]

Comment: @codextor thanks for coming back to me but neither of your suggestions actually make any difference to the script.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Would you be able to show me what that might look like?

Comment: @Codextor The command also uses `-Recurse`, so in that case you do not end the path with `\*`

Comment: @jabra - please take a look at my Answer. it shows what i meant by using `Where-Object` to filter the items instead of using `-Include` in the `G-CI` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compared the names of the files only.  The complete paths will never be the same.

```
$items1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "new" -Include "*.properties", "*.ini" -recurse 
$items2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "old" -Include "*.properties", "*.ini" -recurse 

$diffent = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $items1 -DifferenceObject $items2 -property name -passthru
if ($diffent.count -eq 0) {
  echo "No new files found"
} else {
  echo "The Following files are not in both directories"
  foreach($item in $diffent){
    $path = $item.FullName
    echo "$path"
  }
}
```

```
The Following files are not in both directories
C:\Users\admin\foo\new\file2.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

here is one way to compare the file names from two dirs ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a list of target file types
- converts that to a regex `OR` pattern
- sets the 1st & 2nd dirs
- gets the files from each dir tree and then filters them for the desired file types
  this is used instead of `-Include` since i have found both the `-Include` and the `-Exclude` parameters to be wildly unreliable. [*sigh ...*]
- compares the two lists
- IF the list has something in it, show the `.FullName` for each list item
- IF the list is empty, say so

the code ...

```
$TargetTypes = @(
    'log'
    'txt'
    )
$TT_Regex = $TargetTypes -join '|'

$FirstDir = 'D:\temp\zzz - Copy'
$SecondDir = 'D:\Temp\Test'

$FD_List = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $FirstDir -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Extension -match $TT_Regex 
        }
$SD_List = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SecondDir -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Extension -match $TT_Regex 
        }

$NotInBoth = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FD_List -DifferenceObject $SD_List
if ($NotInBoth)
    {
    Write-Host 'The following files are NOT in both dirs ...'
    $NotInBoth.InputObject.FullName |
        Out-Host
    }
    else
        {
    Write-Host 'Both dirs contain the same file names.'
    }
```

truncated output with different files in the two trees ...

```
The following files are NOT in both dirs ...
D:\Temp\Test\Accounting_-_01-02-2017_-_Accounting.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Accounting_-_02-17-2017_-_Accounting.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Accounting_-_12-30-2016_-_Accounting.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Marketing_-_01-02-2017_-_Marketing.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Marketing_-_02-17-2017_-_Marketing.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Marketing_-_12-30-2016_-_Marketing.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Personnel_-_01-02-2017_-_Personnel.txt
D:\Temp\Test\Personnel_-_02-17-2017_-_Personnel.txt

[*...snip...*] 

D:\temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy\CDelta\Documents\OutList_-_HashSet_-_001.txt
D:\temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy\CDelta\Documents\Setup Log 2018-05-09 #001.txt
D:\temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy\CDelta\Documents\Uninstall Log 2018-05-09 #001.txt
```